# Show and hide elements in Angular

Tags: angularjs

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="XYZController">
{{menuState.show1}}
<div>

<ul ng-show='menuState.show1'>

<li ng-click='stun()'>Stun</li>
<li ng-click='disintegrate()'>Disintegrate</li>
<li ng-click='erase()'>Erase from history</li>
</ul>
<button ng-click='toggleMenu()'>Toggle Menu</button>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
var show2 =false;
var app=angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("XYZController",function($scope){
$scope.menuState.show1=show2;

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In this code It is supposed to Hide the all ng-click elements. BUt it is still showing all.I think my controller is not being linked.Please some one help me out

Answer (score 0):

$scope.menuState is undefined.

Try this:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="XYZController">
{{menuState.show1}}
<div>

<ul ng-show='menuState.show1'>

<li ng-click='stun()'>Stun</li>
<li ng-click='disintegrate()'>Disintegrate</li>
<li ng-click='erase()'>Erase from history</li>
</ul>
<button ng-click='toggleMenu()'>Toggle Menu</button>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
var show2 =false;
var app=angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("XYZController",function($scope){
$scope.menuState = {}
$scope.menuState.show1=show2;

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```